# WebRTC addTrack / addStream after createOffer

Tags: webrtc

I have created a WebRTC Channel for Text Chat only.

When user wishes to have Video / Audio chat, they can turn on the Video / Audio by pressing a button.

In WebRTC, we need to call `navigator.getUserMedia` and add the video stream before we `createOffer`.

But there is a problem, because as soon as we call `getUserMedia`, the browser will ask user for permission to access to the Camera, even though we do not initiate a Video / Audio chat yet.

My question is, is there a way for us to call `navigator.getUserMedia` at later stage and add the stream into the connection?

Comment: It is possible, you need to renegotiate. I'll find an example of that being done on the browser to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You need to do a re-negotiation. It is just another round of Offer/Answer. It can be done at anytime, and by either side.

Check out [play-from-disk-renegotation](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/play-from-disk-renegotation) this shows a peer adding/removing and removing video after it has connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it now!